# Adding Custom path for storage in filesystems.php Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, filesystems

I want to add a path "C:\Folder" for storage purposes in filesystems.php

When I use the below code I get an error:

```
Driver [] is not supported.
```

Code:

```
'c_path' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => "C:/Folder/",
],
```

So how to solve this problem? Can someone please suggest me a solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From terminal run,

```
composer require league/flysystem
```

In your file filesystems.php file

```
   'c_path' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => 'C:\uploads'
    ],
```

then for store your file,

```
Storage::disk('c_path')->put('picture.png', $request->file('picture'));
```